# Python: same program, different print message placement when run

Tags: python, stderr

Error message that I print myself, shows up EITHER top or bottom of the file randomly if I run the same script several times. Why it changes?

Is it because of sys.exit() or because of file=stderr()?

It's from the book. I think the author is using file=stderr() to color the message in the terminal.

Code:

```
import sys

ciphertext = """16 12 8 4 0 1 5 9 13 17 18 14 10 6 2 3 7 11 15"""
COLS = 4
ROWS = 5
key = """ -1 2 -3 4 """

def main():
    cipherlist = list(ciphertext.split())
    validate_col_row(cipherlist)


def validate_col_row(cipherlist):
    """Check that input columns and rows are valid vs message length."""
    factors = []
    len_cipher = len(cipherlist)
    for i in range(2, len_cipher):  # range excludes 1-column ciphers
        if len_cipher % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)

    print(f'\nLength of cipher = {len_cipher}')
    print(f'Acceptable column/row values include: {factors}')
    print()

    if ROWS * COLS != len_cipher:
        print('\nError - Input columns and rows not factors of length '
              'of cipher. Terminating program.', file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit()


main()
```

So the output is either this:

```
Error - Input columns and rows not factors of length of cipher. Terminating program.

Ciphertext = 16 12 8 4 0 1 5 9 13 17 18 14 10 6 2 3 7 11 15

Trying 4 columns
Trying 5 rows
Trying key =  -1 2 -3 4 

Length of cipher = 19
Acceptable column/row values include: []
```

or:

```
Ciphertext = 16 12 8 4 0 1 5 9 13 17 18 14 10 6 2 3 7 11 15

Trying 4 columns
Trying 5 rows
Trying key =  -1 2 -3 4 

Length of cipher = 19
Acceptable column/row values include: []


Error - Input columns and rows not factors of length of cipher. Terminating program.
```

Answer (score 0):

`stdout` in a terminal is line-buffered, and buffered when `stdout` is a file.

`stderr` stream may makes it to the file faster because it's always unbuffered.